# Is PayPal's "PNREF" always 12 characters?

Tags: mysql, paypal

Does anyone know if PayPal's "PNREF" (returned from zero-dollar authorizations) is **always 12 characters?**

This I ask because I want to optimize my mySQL storage.

And also, I trust SO's answer more than PP's  :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't "optimize" your storage. Not only do server-grade terabyte sized drives cost just a few hundred dollars, making the cost of storing a handful of bytes nearly zero, but `VARCHAR(255)` columns only take up as much space as you have content because they are **variable length**.

If you ran a million transactions and saved ten bytes on each, you've saved all of ten megabytes of data, or about $0.0001 worth of storage. I'm presuming if you've run a million transactions you can afford the bytes. The PayPal fees will be literally *several quadrillion times higher*.

In actuality there's zero savings between 12 characters in `VARCHAR(12)` and `VARCHAR(255)`. Internally these are represented as a single length byte plus *N* bytes for the content. For regular 7-bit values that means 13 bytes per entry.

The only difference is you're arbitrarily limiting the former to 12 characters and will get truncation errors (if this flag is set, as it is on newer versions of MySQL) if you insert longer values, or you'll lose data and have no idea until it's probably too late to fix it.

Just use `VARCHAR(255)` so that your code doesn't explode when PayPal decides today's the day to use 14 characters. These things can change without warning and without any logical reason.